# Encryption bad password problem with Dell inspiron 7566

Tags: encryption

I have set up Ubuntu 18.04 and encrypted the disk, after an apt-get upgrade that also upgraded the kernel ,i have encountered a problem where i input the correct encryption password and the decryption is not working, i used an older kernel so far for the decryption. I accidentally did recently another apt get upgrade and the same problem occurs again also with the old kernel i was using.

I know the encryption password but it is not working, is there something possible i can do?

Updated:
I created a live usb and got into the disk, the encryption password is working, i managed to copy some files, is there something i can do to fix the problem since i can access the disk ?

Comment: This means you don't know the password.

Comment: The interface does not understand the password or something, is there a workaround ? Can i take my data with a live usb and the encryption password ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the layout of the keyboard was wrong, from a live USB i changed the encryption passphrase to numbers only, this solved the problem.

I believe that the problem is related to the initramfs configuration. When using the initramfs bussy box i could not write English characters. From the layout of initramfs the us value was second regarding the layout(i don't know for sure if this was before the upgrade or if this is the root of the issue).